# Finding two different minimal primary decompositions

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have the ideal $$\langle x^2, xy^3\rangle$$

where I've found a minimal primary decomposition to be $(x) \cap (x^2,y^3)$. Now I've been asked to find a second minimal primary decomposition but I'm not sure of how to go about it? I know that the associated primes of a second decomposition will have to be the same as the first ($(x), (x,y)$), but I'm not sure how to find this second minimal decomposition.

Comment: The minimal primary component is unique. So, have you tried the ideal $(x^2, x+y^3)$ with $(x)$?

Comment: Whats the thinking here behind coming up with that? What are the intermediary steps?

Comment: The minimal primary component is unique. The rest was trial and error. However, you cannot find another one which is monomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{align}
\langle x^2, xy^3 \rangle = \langle x^2, xy^3, xy^7 \rangle &= \langle x^2, xy^3, x\rangle \cap \langle x^2, xy^3,y^7\rangle \\
&= \langle x\rangle \cap \langle x^2, xy^3,y^7\rangle
\end{align}
Also the term $\langle x^2, xy^3,y^7\rangle$ is irreducible (check) in a noetherian ring and so is primary.

The *trick* appears to be adding another term that is 'un-needed' and splitting and simplifying.

Edit: The power of $7$ in $xy^7$ could be replaced by any integer $\geq 3$, I just like 7.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, it's been giving me a lot of grief since the support class

Comment: No worries, took me ages to work it out. Good luck!

Comment: Have you worked out how to do it for Q1 on HW6, 'cause this doesn't work for that. @lego323

Comment: Not without the help of Macaulay2 to simplify intersections... @chilliBeanDream

Comment: Can't you add in a term at any point which would be removed and split that down? E.g. I got $(x^2) \cap (y^3,x^3) \cap (y^2,x^4) \cap (y)$ and $(x^2) \cap (y^2,x) \cap (y)$ as two minimal decompositions of HW6 Q1

Comment: @IanBaker the first one isn't minimal, but yeah I think that's the general idea

Comment: The way I finally did the question was to take $\langle x^2 \rangle \cap \langle y^3, x^3 y^2, x^4 \rangle = \langle x^2 y^3, x^3 y^2, x^4 \rangle = \langle x^2 y^3 + x^4, x^3 y^2, x^4 \rangle = \langle x^2 \rangle \cap \langle y^3 + x^2, x^3 y^2, x^4 \rangle$

Comment: Wait, why's it not minimal? What can you get rid of?

Comment: Oh, its irredundant but not minimal, right?

Comment: Answer is $<x^2> \cap <y> \cap <x^4,x^3y^2,y^3>$ and $<x^2>\cap<y> \cap<x^4,x^3y^2,x^2y^3,y^4>$

Comment: This is a very good answer. I somehow thought one could not find another embedded monomial component.